# Importing Application data in PeopleSoft 9.2

Tags: peoplesoft

I want to import Recruitment data from web application into our record but the CI of related component is not working.It's giving an error saying

> First operand of . is NULL, so cannot access member GetParameter. (180,236) HRS_APPLICANT_TRACKING.RelatedActions.AaaS.ProxyGate.OnExecute  Name:ProxyGate  PCPC:435  Statement:8
>   Called from:HRS_APP_PROFILE.GBL.PreBuild  Statement:5

So i want to know if there are any other options to import data into records without using CI.
Kindly help.

Regards,
Aiman Farid

Comment: How are you importing into the CI? Is it Excel to CI or peoplecode? It may be a security issue.

Comment: I am importing through PeopleCode

Comment: Could you paste your code? And also make sure you have permission on this CI.